# Sprite Kit Availability Pre iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

As far as I know, Sprite Kit was introduced along with iOS 7 and is targeted for devices that are currently running >= iOS 7. If so, what will happen to any games that are made with Sprite Kit that are downloaded on devices with < iOS 7?

Comment: I think it's safe to say that if you don't specify a Sprite Kit app to require iOS 7.0 then Apple will not let you pass approval. So there won't be any Sprite Kit apps available for download on devices that don't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not properly conditionally avoid calling SpriteKit code or do not specify a minimum required iOS version of 7.0, your app will crash.

Download the iOS 6 Simulator files (in Xcode Preferences) to test.

Comment: You should also specify the minimum OS correctly in your App metadata. If you absolutely need SpriteKit, don't target any OS below below 7.0.